# Hibernate 5.1 with Infinispan 7.0 2nd level cache compatibility (no Java 8)?

Tags: hibernate, infinispan

Impossible to find the information anywhere, so I ask here in case someone already face this problem.

I'm trying to activate Hibernate 2LC with Infinispan by using the hibernate-infinispan module. This module rely on Infinispan 8 that require Java 8, but our application is only Java 7. So I was wondering if it's possible to use this module but change its dependency to make it work with Infinispan 7.0. I'm not really confident, but I will give it a try later. But in case, if someone already make infinispan 2LC work sucessfully with Hibernate 5.1 and Java 7 the information could help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC Infinispan 6 -> 7 and then again 7 -> 8 caused a lot of breaking changes in the hibernate-infinispan module of Hibernate.  So I think simply grabbing the hibernate-infinispan module for use with Infinispan 8 and just updating the Infinispan version it relies on to be Infinispan 7 instead is not going to work.  But [TIAS](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Try-It-and-See-(chat)-(TIAS).html).